# Glxinfo shows Mesa but I'm using Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, opengl

I am trying to update my GPU driver in order to use OpenGL 4+ (Ubuntu 18.04). I have installed the recommended Nvidia driver, however when I run

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

I still get the following output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Showing that OpenGL is still on Mesa and `llvmpipe` renderer string, instead of showing the Nvidia GPU.

When I check which drivers are used, I get the following output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Additionally, I am unable to run `nvidia-settings`, as this error pops up:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:2470): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:39:28.467: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 18:39:28.469: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 18:39:28.469: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Some extra information:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amota.png) of running `nvidia-smi`

This is the recommended nvidia driver, installed by running `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430` and rebooting the system (`sudo reboot`).

I have also updated the error message shown when running `nvidia-settings`

Not sure if it is useful information, but the system runs on a remote server, which I am accessing using a remote desktop with Plasma KDE.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1165408/edit) your question and add more detail for us.  What is the recommended NVIDIA driver that you installed? Where did you install it from?  What does the output of `nvidia-smi` show?  Also, have you rebooted since you installed the NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: @Terrance added more information in the post as per your request